# Is it possible to process State data before a Widget is disposed?

Tags: flutter, dispose, lifecycle, flutter-state

### The Problem

I have a Widget that I reuse in my app, say the default "you have pressed the button this many times" Widget.

I have added an asynchronous `saveData` function to this Widget, which takes the `int` in the `State` and stores it (say in the Shared Preferences). The rationale is that I can store only once, instead of after every single change.

Now I use this Widget in an `AlertDialog` called by `showDialog`, and I use it again in a `BottomSheet` called by `showModalBottomSheet`. Additionally, I'd want to use it in a page of a `PageView`.

### The Question

Is there a way to get the data to save when the Dialog or BottomSheet is Widget is disposed, or otherwise from the enclosing Widget (sheet/dialog)? I would rather not create two variations of my reused Widget just because it is wrapped in a different Widget, and pulling the State out of my reused Widget into the two parent Widgets also seems unnecessary.

### What I tried

I've been trying to use `dispose` and `deactivate`, but since I'm trying to use (a snapshot of) a Widget `State` variable, I couldn't do it: Doing asynchronous work and then calling super caused an error saying I failed to call super, and the other way around tells me I can't use the State after the Widget has been unmounted.

Comment: May be wrap into InheritedWidget to store value?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DmitryRodionov, in the end I opted to use a GlobalKey to invoke the `saveData` function from the parent, and keep all the actual data within the reused Widget itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, trying to intercept a dispose action was not a stable solution (esp. when using the `State` too).

I ended up giving my reused Widget an optional `Key`, and use a `GlobalKey` if I want to upload from outside the Widget (i.e. a submit button in the enclosing PageView page). In case of the BottomSheet, I've now simply set it to auto-save the value each time it changes if no key is present. It works for now, but is not ideal (and if anyone is aware of a better solution, I'm still interested :p).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to return data from the dialogs and the ModalBottomsheet, right?

```
var result = await showDialog(...);

var resultModal = await showModalBottom(...);
```

And inside your Dialog or ModalBottomSheet you return it in the Navigator.pop

```
Navigator.pop(context, myResult);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It's not quite what I'm looking for, since in reality (this was not clear from my question) I'm using the reused widget in a PageView page too, which is never popped/dismissed, but does disappear from the screen (I mixed up dismiss and dispose in my question, I'll improve it a bit).